# Site Converter - Website Copier

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

Does anybody know of a software program that will convert a website built with PHP, JSON and jquery into a mainly HTML format. We need to do a conversion for SEO purposes and don't want to have to rewrite the whole site.

Comment: Convert it all to HTML **AND** retain any of the functionality you had with PHP, JSON and jQuery?  Impossible.  However, there are actually ways to achieve SEO while using PHP, JSON and jQuery but that's a discussion for a different question.

Comment: How would doing that help SEO?

Comment: PHP, JSON and jQuery produce HTML pages which should have as much SEO mojo as static HTML pages would.

Answer (score 6):

HTML is a language used for markup, PHP is an object oriented functional language. You cannot convert one to the other, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to make sure that you have nothing but .HTML extensions on your public URLs for SEO purposes:

1. Someone's selling you a line of BS.
2. You need access to your server configuration.
3. You don't have to convert anything but your links.

The .PHP extension is the default file extension configured to be sent from Apache to the PHP engine for parsing. You can change what file extension gets parsed in your configuration file.

http://encodable.com/parse_html_files_as_php/

This will allow you to keep .HTM files static and have .HTML files parsed as if they were .PHP files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:  http://www.httrack.com/

It will only return a static HTML site.  But it might be a good base for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only thing which really knows what type of file you're using is the server itself, it does not really matter *what* you're using on the back end. Most search engines are smart enough to know that so they don't really care so much. Now, *people* might care. *People* might say, "Hm, well, this is .html, that means that this person must have a flat file which is constantly being updated," but I doubt it.

If you're really concerned about having a `.html` extension, then you can fake it by using htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

If that is placed in a .htaccess file at the root of your site, it will redirect all requests which end with `.html` to a corresponding page with `.php`. It will do that transparently both to the user and to the crawlers.

Of course, every link on your site will need to convert from linking to `.php`, but it will replace the impossible task of using only `.html` files with the annoying task of replacing all of your `.php` links.

As to removing JavaScript, well, you could do that, or you could design your site in such a way that it still uses AJAX but it works with the search engines instead of against them. The biggest trick is to make sure that your site can work with as little AJAX as possible and then use AJAX to supplement. We've come a long way from requiring that all websites work in lynx, but it is still good practice to make sure that they are still sane without the benefit of JS/CSS.

Besides, search engines are getting smarter. Google has been working to read AJAX intelligently since [2009](http://www.internetnews.com/dev-news/article.php/3842916/Google+Says+Have+Your+AJAX+and+SEO+Too.htm). But even if they weren't, there are plenty of [articles](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-for-ajax/19138/) out there on using AJAX without hurting SEO.

There is no need to nerf your site because of SEO -- You can have your AJAX and SEO too.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to accomplish if there is a lot of dynamic data. For a simple website you can just cache every page and make that your new website. I am not sure how useful that would be. For example if you have forms or other user input fields then things will just not work. In any case this is how you do it using wget.

```
$ wget -m http://www.example.com/
```

More reading [here](http://fosswire.com/post/2008/04/create-a-mirror-of-a-website-with-wget/).